# Magento 2: How to make Message Manager showing specific message one time only?

Tags: magento2, global-messages, success-message

I have a page that welcomes a customer with a message manager like this:

```
$this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__("Welcome to test section"));
```

the problem is this message will keep appears if the customer reload the page again, how can i make sure this message wont show up again (not forever) , lets say for specific amount of time or i can put an identifier to the message manager??

Comment: I am not sure how you are implanting this. But you have an option to use store cookies, and create a cookie for it. Something like this https://magenest.com/en/manage-cookies-in-magento-2/